# How to remove #038 in url when using javascript in wordpress editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Im editing the code in wordpress page editor

```
<script>
window.location.href="?page_id=364&id=15&catname=پەیامی رۆژ;"
</script>
```

when click this page it navigate like this :

> url?page_id=364#038;id=15&catname==پەیامی رۆژ;

But I need url?page_id=364&id=15&catname==پەیامی رۆژ;

Im using "&" also.. but it doesn't work.

How to remove #038 in url ?

Comment: Very strange that one of & work fine and another not. May be they are written in different layout? Don't know matter this or not, but check.

Comment: no one is not working